# Using work group file with the DB connection

Tags: ms-access, sas, ms-access-2010

first I have a ACCESS 2003 (.mdb) file with no workgroup file(.mdw) and a password on database. The thing is I want to specify in my SAS code that I want to be connected to the DB on read-only mode. Here the command that I use :

```
LIBNAME bdmdf ACCESS "W:\DB.mdb" access=readonly pw=PASSWORD; (Note that PASSWORD have no quotes)
```

The thing is when I specify "read-only" , he seem that it mandatory to specify a .mdw file.

The problem here is I'm using ACCESS 2010, so from what I read ACCESS 2010 no longer support workgroup file. I found that I can do "DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWorkgroupAdministrator
" to open the wizard and create the .mdw file but I don't seem to find where I can edit the workgroup.

Finaly the question is , is it mandatory to use workgroup with the read-only parameter? If yes is it a good idea to just create a workgroup(.mdw) and not really use it. If not how I edit my workgroup file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*"... ACCESS 2010 no longer support workgroup file."*

That situation is confusing.  ULS (user-level security) uses the MDW workgroup information file to store information about Access security users and groups.  Microsoft introduced the ACCDB file format with Access 2007.  ACCDB no longer supports ULS.  However Access 2007 and later still fully support ULS with the older MDB database file format.

*"is it mandatory to use workgroup with the read-only parameter?"*

No, not from the Access side.  I've no idea whether SAS configuration details complicate the situation.

If you need to use the MDW file for your SAS connection, you can find out where it is located by opening Access, then the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>) and using `SystemDb` to find it.

```
? DAO.DBEngine.SystemDB
C:\Users\hans\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Access\System.mdw
```

Also beware there are 2 types of passwords which can be associated with Access db files.

1. Database password: A single password attached to the db file.  All connection attempts must supply this password.  It has nothing to do with ULS.
2. User passwords:  These apply with ULS, with separate passwords for each defined user.

Sorry for throwing so much information at you.  But I want to encourage you to confirm which of those password types you're using and make sure you're using the correct SAS connection options to distinguish between those password types.  However, I don't know anything about SAS connection options and configuration.

Comment: If it's helpful, SAS would be using the ACE engine to access the .mdb file (so this should be no different from any other third party software).

Comment: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/acpcref/63181/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0qmltkh8j50qrn1qsflopy10vp5.htm  - it looks like DBPASSWORD is the proper PASSWORD option for 1.) and PASSWORD is for 2.)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for the explanation about ULS very useful. For everyone information here is what I did and it work perfectly

```
libname savesdb odbc 
    required="driver=Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb);                    
                      dbq=W:\BD.mdb; 
                      uid=admin; 
                      pwd=PASSWORD" 
    access=readonly 
    ;
```